# SSO/IDP to use for local testing (not via internet)

Tags: localhost, single-sign-on

I want to test a homegrown product that can act as SP during SSO login. For this purpose I want to install a SSO enabled server on my machine locally.

Posts i have searched for suggest for using a IDP hosted on internet(like testshib), but testing with IDP hosted on internet would require a public IP where the IDP can post the authentication response. But I dont have a public IP, so I want to install it locally. Please suggest.

I tried using Gluu Server but was not able to get it working.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Haven't found the solution yet. Did you stumble upon any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a tunneling tool like https://ngrok.com/docs

It will give you a `http(s)://random-subdomain.ngrok.io` that tunnels to a port specified on `localhost`.

You can also inspect and replay traffic easily (even binary), which is helpful for troubleshooting.  There is a picture on link 1.

Just be aware that you are publicly exposing your port by default. I highly recommend whitelisting your ip: https://ngrok.com/docs#whitelist

That's not perfect, especially if you're in a large NATed environment, but it helps.

Comment: please post how to do them.not just the sites.